# How to calculate and apply exponential function to a time series

Tags: python, time-series, exponential

I currently have the below time series and have a 4th degree polynomial as my best fit line. How do I calculate the correct coffeccients and apply an exponetial fucntion to this series? My goal is to get some type of growth rate.

```
data2 = StringIO("""

date        value
09-Oct-17   0.304
10-Nov-17   0.316
26-Nov-17   0.636
12-Dec-17   0.652
28-Dec-17   0.639
13-Jan-18   0.623
02-Mar-18   0.619
18-Mar-18   0.608
19-Apr-18   0.605
05-May-18   0.625
06-Jun-18   0.639
22-Jun-18   0.663
08-Jul-18   0.64
24-Jul-18   0.623
09-Aug-18   0.632
28-Oct-18   0.736
""")

df2 = pd.read_table(data2, delim_whitespace=True)

df2.loc[:, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2.loc[:, "date"], format="%d-%b-%y")

y_values2 = df2.loc[:, "value"]
x_values2 = np.linspace(0,1,len(df2.loc[:, "value"]))
poly_degree = 4

coeffs2 = np.polyfit(x_values2, y_values2, poly_degree)
poly_eqn2 = np.poly1d(coeffs2)
 y_hat2 = poly_eqn2(x_values2)

 plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

 plt.plot(df.loc[:, "date"], df.loc[:,"value"] ,"ro",color='green')
 plt.plot(df.loc[:, "date"],y_hat)
 plt.plot(df2.loc[:, "date"], df2.loc[:,"value"] ,"ro",color='red')
 plt.plot(df2.loc[:, "date"],y_hat2)
 plt.title('WSC-10-50')
 plt.ylabel('NDVI')
 plt.xlabel('Date')
 plt.savefig("NDVI_plot.png")
```

Comment: The coefficients are already calculated: `print(poly_eqn2)`

Comment: What are you referring to by "correct coefficients"? You already have the coefficients for the 4th-degree fit `poly_eqn2` and the estimated values  `y_hat2` from this fit.

Comment: From my understanding an exponential function needs a k, t and tau value. Wouldnt the coefficient for a 4th degree polynomial be different?